# VerifyError In Eclipse Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, verifyerror

I configure eclipse Helios Service Release 2 , eclipse properly download and configure ADT and SDK,I import my old project into newly configured development environment,its showing no error . In an activity I'm creating object of another class that giving me an exception as "VerifyError" , I check my JDK in project and eclipse its 2.2 , I also check my project libraries that also have the "Android.jar" , but don't know what I'm doing wrong ,I'm facing this type of problem for the 1st time,When I debug my code and control reached at a line where I am creating object of another class I press f6 it stuck and saying as "No Source Code Found" ,Please guide me where I am coding wrong . . .
I'll be thankful,for detail of error see attachment image . . . [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my projects after doing the Android ADT , and Java updates.

Try these steps:

1. Remove links to your external libraries in your Android project.
2. Move all your external libraries (including Google Ad libraries) to \libs folder inside your Android project.
3. Re-link your libraries, that now exist in the Project\libs directory.

Hopefully this will help.